# How to add a button without a repetition when there is a mapped function top of it in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I want to add a button to the end of the screen but I guess because of the mapping function button gets repeated and adds a button for each value.

App.js [Parent Component]:

```
 const quizElements = questions.map (quiz => (
    <Quiz 
      question={quiz.question}  
      key={quiz.question}
      correctAnswer={quiz.correct_answer}
      incorrectAnswers={quiz.incorrect_answers}
    />
  ))
```

Quiz.js [Child Component]:

```
return (
        <>
            <div className="quiz-parent">
                <div>
                   <div>                        
                        <p>{decodedQuestion}</p>
                        <p>answer: {decodedCorrectAnswer} </p>
                        <form className="answer-btn">
                            {finalAnswers} 
                            <button>Button 1</button>
                        </form>  
                        <button>Button 2</button>
                    </div>
                    <button>Button 3</button>
                </div>
                <button>Button 4</button>
            </div>
            <button>Button 5</button>
        </>
    )

}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

of course, I can add a button to the parent element and pass it to the child as a prop but the problem is all of the data for setup the function for the button is on the child component. I already tried to pass the data to the parent and write the function there but it didn't work so if any of you can help me with this I would really appreciate it.